# Projeto Maven - Carrega no tomcat, mas não executa

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, spring

Estou com um projeto do `Maven` que, apesar das mensagens exibidas no terminal do Eclipse informarem que o `Deploy` foi feito com sucesso. Quando digito a URL no browser, recebo um erro 404; em seguida ao abrir o manager do `Tomcat`, tento inicia-lo, mas também recebo um erro.

A saída do terminal do Eclipse, operação de `deploy`:

```
Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-war-plugin:2.1.1:war (default-war) @ example ---
[INFO] Packaging webapp
[INFO] Assembling webapp [example] in [C:\Users\Kleber\git\maven_example\target\example-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
[INFO] Processing war project
[INFO] Copying webapp resources [C:\Users\Kleber\git\maven_example\src\main\webapp]
[INFO] Webapp assembled in [827 msecs]
[INFO] Building war: C:\Users\Kleber\git\maven_example\target\example-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:deploy (default-cli) @ example <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:deploy (default-cli) @ example ---
[INFO] Deploying war to http://localhost:8080/webappExample  
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Uploading: http://localhost:8080/manager/text/deploy?path=%2FwebappExample
Uploaded: http://localhost:8080/manager/text/deploy?path=%2FwebappExample (13855 KB at 56318.8 KB/sec)

[INFO] tomcatManager status code:200, ReasonPhrase:OK
[INFO] OK - Deployed application at context path /webappExample
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 11.379s
[INFO] Finished at: Sun Apr 20 14:17:44 GMT-03:00 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 13M/223M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

O código fonte do projeto pode ser visto aqui:

https://github.com/klebermo/maven_example

Alguém tem idéia do que está errado no projeto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bem, depois de mais testes, eu descobri que o erro era em uma de minhas classes. Um dos atributos dessa classe estava com o tipo errado, e por isso o sistema não conseguia carregar esse atributo na inicialização da aplicação (o atributo tinha a anotação Autowired).

Eu descobri isso executando o tomcat a partir do terminal, e acompanhando a saída dele. Isso porque não consegui uma forma de fazer com que essa saída fosse exibida no console do Eclipse.